# Cannot call function twice, woocommerce, gravity forms

Tags: woocommerce, gravityforms

I have successfully used the following code to create a woocommerce order after gravity form submission.

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_56', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 ); function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) { global $woocommerce; // use this to find out $entry output var_dump($entry); 

// set some variables 
$user_id =rgar( $entry, '97' );
$product_id = rgar( $entry, '71' );
$quantity = rgar( $entry, '73' ); 
$note = rgar( $entry, '53' );
$product = wc_get_product($product_id); 

$address = array( 'first_name' => rgar( $entry, '98' ), 'last_name' => rgar( $entry, '99' ), 'company' => rgar( $entry, '' ), 'email' => rgar( $entry, '83' ), 'phone' => rgar( $entry, '84' ), 'address_1' => rgar( $entry, '88.1' ), 'address_2' => rgar( $entry, '88.2' ), 'city' => rgar( $entry, '88.3' ), 'state' => rgar( $entry, '88.4' ), 'postcode' => rgar( $entry, '88.5' ), 'country' => rgar( $entry, '88.6' ), );

$order = wc_create_order(); $order->set_customer_id( $user_id ); $order->add_product( wc_get_product($product_id), $quantity, $prices); foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) { $item->add_meta_data( 'Booking Request', $note, true ); } $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' ); $order->calculate_totals(); $order->update_status( 'pending payment', 'pending', TRUE); $order->add_order_note( $note );
                                            $coupon_code = rgar( $entry, '105' ); $order->apply_coupon($coupon_code);
```

The issue I am faced with is that I need a different form to also create a woocommerce order upon submission. I don't know how to do this as when I create a code reflecting the correct form id it tells me it cannot call the function more than once.

What should I do? is there another function or do I somehow add to this original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the hook (gform_after_submission) being recycled, but the second part, "post_to_third_party."
That function can't be redefined.  You can either rename that, or just make your after_submission a bit more modular for all forms.

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'post_to_third_party', 10, 2 );
function post_to_third_party( $entry, $form ) {

    switch ($form['id']) {

        case 56:
            // do your code for form 56.
            break;

        case 12:
            // do stuff if form id is 12... or whatever.
            break;
    }
}
```